# Java Apache Spark flatMaps & Data Wrangling

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have to pivot the data in a file and then store it in another file. I am having some difficulty pivoting the data.

I have multiple files, that contain data which looks somewhat like I show below. The columns are variable lengths. I am trying to merge the files, first. But for some reason, the output is not correct. I haven't even tried the pivot method, but am not sure how to use it either.

How can this be achieved?

```
File 1:
0,26,27,30,120
201008,100,1000,10,400
201009,200,2000,20,500
201010,300,3000,30,600

File 2:
0,26,27,30,120,145
201008,100,1000,10,400,200
201009,200,2000,20,500,100
201010,300,3000,30,600,150

File 3:
0,26,27,120,145
201008,100,10,400,200
201009,200,20,500,100
201010,300,30,600,150

Output:
201008,26,100
201008,27,1000
201008,30,10
201008,120,400
201008,145,200
201009,26,200
201009,27,2000
201009,30,20
201009,120,500
201009,145,100
.....
```

I am not quite familiar with Spark, but am trying to use flatMap and flatMapValues. I am not sure how I can use it for now, but would appreciate some guidance.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ExecutionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        Logger.getLogger("org.spark_project").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        Logger.getLogger("io.netty").setLevel(Level.WARN);
        log.info("Starting...");
        // Step 1: Create a SparkContext.
        boolean isRunLocally = Boolean.valueOf(args[0]);
        String filePath = args[1];

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Variable File").set("serializer",
                "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        if (isRunLocally) {
            log.info("System is running in local mode");
            conf.setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g");
        }

        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(session.sparkContext());
        jsc.textFile(filePath, 2)
           .map(new Function<String, String[]>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public String[] call(String v1) throws Exception {
                    return StringUtils.split(v1, ",");
                }                       
            })
            .foreach(new VoidFunction<String[]>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public void call(String[] t) throws Exception {
                    for (String string : t) {
                        log.info(string);
                    }   
                }

            });     
    }

}
```

Comment: Any progress your side. Interesting thing with no other answers.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't been able to figure how to get this working. I was hopeful to get some advice here.

Comment: I am looking, quite hard

Comment: This is all I could get, but not sure how to implement:
It looks to me like what you are trying to do is not actually a pivot but rather a simple flat map.

If you think as the row header as being the column names (I'll refer to these as c1 c2 c3...) and each row as values (let's call them v1 v2 v3...) then you want to convert

(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5) to:

v1,c2,v2
v1,c3,v3
v1,c4,v4

etc, and you can do that with a flatmap.

Comment: trying.  how many recs per file on average?

Comment: it could be a lot

Comment: Would a file fit in a 2gb partition?

Comment: I see a way to do this, but I only really use Scala, would that be an issue?

Comment: We are doing this in Java, but if you have a way in Scala, maybe I might be able to convert it to Java.

Comment: it is not a regular problem

Comment: The points is num columns per file can vary as well, interesting case

Comment: I think I have a solution soon, but in Scala. A little busy.

Comment: Looking good, but day over. Involves RDD and DF and zipping. Should post tomorrow. Solved your end? I am 50% way thru. It will be Scala though.

Comment: See if you can get the gist and complete yourself.

Comment: Added in between things the 2nd of 3 parts. You should be able to finish off.

Comment: Please reveal your thoughts, you will need to do Java stuff which is stiff, convert to Scala.

Comment: Posted the solution, am expecting some credits here for the amount of effort.

Comment: This was a fair bit of effort. Following?

Comment: Odd the upvoting on the question and nothing on the answer. What is it all coming to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Scala as I am not a JAVA person, you should be able to adapt. And add sorting, cache, etc.

Data is as follows, 3 files with duplicate entry evident, get rid of that if you do not want.

```
      0, 5,10, 15  20
 202008, 5,10, 15, 20
 202009,10,20,100,200
```

8 rows generated above.

```
      0,888,999
 202008,  5, 10
 202009, 10, 20
```

4 rows generated above.

```
     0, 5
202009,10
```

1 row, which is a duplicate.

```
// Bit lazy with columns names, but anyway.

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name  
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import spark.implicits._

val inputPath: String = "/FileStore/tables/g*.txt"  
val rdd = spark.read.text(inputPath)
  .select(input_file_name, $"value")   
  .as[(String, String)] 
  .rdd

val rdd2 = rdd.zipWithIndex
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(x => (x._1._1, x._2, x._1._2.split(",").toList.map(_.toInt)))  
val rdd4 = rdd3.map { case (pfx, pfx2, list) => (pfx,pfx2,list.zipWithIndex) }
val df = rdd4.toDF()
df.show(false)
df.printSchema()

val df2 = df.withColumn("rankF", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"_1").orderBy($"_2".asc)))
df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema()

val df3 = df2.withColumn("elements", explode($"_3"))
df3.show(false)
df3.printSchema()

val df4 = df3.select($"_1", $"rankF", $"elements".getField("_1"), $"elements".getField("_2")).toDF("fn", "line_num", "val", "col_pos")
df4.show(false)
df4.printSchema()

df4.createOrReplaceTempView("df4temp")

val df51 = spark.sql("""SELECT hdr.fn, hdr.line_num, hdr.val AS pfx, hdr.col_pos
                          FROM df4temp hdr
                         WHERE hdr.line_num <> 1
                           AND hdr.col_pos = 0
                     """) 
df51.show(100,false)

val df52 = spark.sql("""SELECT t1.fn, t1.val AS val1, t1.col_pos, t2.line_num, t2.val AS val2
                          FROM df4temp t1, df4temp t2
                         WHERE t1.col_pos  <> 0
                           AND t1.col_pos  = t2.col_pos 
                           AND t1.line_num <> t2.line_num
                           AND t1.line_num = 1
                           AND t1.fn       = t2.fn
                     """)
df52.show(100,false)

df51.createOrReplaceTempView("df51temp")
df52.createOrReplaceTempView("df52temp")

val df53 = spark.sql("""SELECT DISTINCT t1.pfx, t2.val1, t2.val2
                          FROM df51temp t1, df52temp t2
                         WHERE t1.fn = t2.fn 
                           AND t1.line_num = t2.line_num
                     """)
df53.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+------+----+----+
|pfx   |val1|val2|
+------+----+----+
|202008|888 |5   |
|202009|999 |20  |
|202009|20  |200 |
|202008|5   |5   |
|202008|10  |10  |
|202009|888 |10  |
|202008|15  |15  |
|202009|5   |10  |
|202009|10  |20  |
|202009|15  |100 |
|202008|20  |20  |
|202008|999 |10  |
+------+----+----+
```

What we see is Data Wrangling requiring massaged data for tempview creations and JOINing with SQL appropriately.

The key here is to know how to massage the data to make things easy. Note no groupBy etc. Per file, with varying length stuff, JOINing not attempted in RDD, too inflexible. Rank shows line#, so you know the first line with the 0 business.

This is what we call Data Wrangling. This is what we also call hard work for a few points on SO. This is one of my best efforts, and also one of the last of such efforts.

Weakness of solution is a lot of work to get 1st record of a file, there are alternatives. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-display-first-line-of-file/ preprocesing is what I would realistically consider.

Comment: In that case some credit would be appreciated. Some thinking done here for sure. Interesting use case plus different features to apply. May be pivot would be possible but I could not see it. My advice is Scala is easier than Java.

Comment: I dont know how to give credit, but thank you so much for that. I will be pasting the Java code that did the same soon. Thanks once again